# Read CSV file with skip rows until we find certain no of columns using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I want to read CSV file using python by skiprows dynamically after condition.

Condition - whenever I found 6 cols in CSV read from there or either when i find col names sequence as those 6 cols.

File.csv

```
Col1,col2,col3

1,2,3

13,u,u

,,,

,,,

Col1,col2,col3,col4

1,2,3,4

13,u,u,y

,,,

,,,

Col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6

1,2,3,4,5,6

qw,ers,hh,yj,df,ji
```

Now I'm reading this file using `pandas.read_csv()`

I know that at 10th row i have required cols.

`pandas.read_csv("file.csv", skiprows=10, header=None)`

Want to skip this dynamically by skipping rows when we 6 cols or either in this sequence col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6.

```py
start =  df.loc[df.FILE-START == 'col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6'].index[0]
df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows = start + 1)
```

Tried this but it's not working.

Comment: Why does the csv file contain different numbers of columns?  That seems like a bad mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

A more robust version using `csv` module:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import io

with open('File.csv') as fp:
    while True:
        pos = fp.tell()
        reader = csv.reader(io.StringIO(fp.readline()))
        row = next(reader)
        if len(row) == 6:
            break
    fp.seek(pos)
    df = pd.read_csv(fp)
```

---

**Old answer**

You can read the file line by line until you found 6 columns or 5 commas (take care if you have quotes and comma between them. But it's fine for a simple csv file:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('File.csv') as fp:
    while True:
        pos = fp.tell()
        row = fp.readline()
        if row.count(',') == 5:
            break
    fp.seek(pos)
    df = pd.read_csv(fp)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
0    1    2    3    4    5    6
1   qw  ers   hh   yj   df   ji
```

Comment: your solution is great Corralien. but I think Keshav is asking about "Col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6" this as an input itself.

Comment: I'm not really sure "**by skipping rows when we 6 cols** or either in this sequence col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6*

Comment: Thanks Corralien for quick help.

Answer (score 2):

Another option with pandas' [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) *constructor* :

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open("file.csv") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    rows = [row for row in csv_reader if len(row) == 6]
    data_six = {"columns": rows[0], "data": rows[1:]}​
    df = pd.DataFrame(**data_six)
```

As explained by @Corralien, with this approach, pandas lose the ability to infer data types for each column since `csv.reader` returns always a list of strings.

> csv.**reader**(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)
> Return a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given csvfile. csvfile can
> be any object which supports the iterator protocol and returns a
> string each time its _*next_*() method is called — file objects and
> list objects are both suitable. **Each row read from the csv file is
> returned as a list of strings.**
>
> *Source* : [[docs.python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)]

Output :

```
print(df)

  Col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
0    1    2    3    4    5    6
1   qw  ers   hh   yj   df   ji
```

*Nota: this assumes that your csv file always ends up with six columns data and with a unique header.*

Comment: Hi. The problem with this method is that you lost the ability to Pandas to infer data types but it's a good solution too. +1

Comment: Hi Corralien, can you explain why please ? What if we chain it with `convert_dtypes` ?

Comment: `csv.reader` doesn't cast to int or float, you get only strings. So if you have a numeric columns, it will be set to object. Yes it's probably a good idea to use `convert_dtypes`. I'm agree with that.

Comment: I updated the csv file so we get numeric-like values in the first column and when using `convert_dtypes`, `print(df.dtypes)` returns _String_ for all the columns, dunno why!

Comment: To be honest, I can never get `convert_dtypes` to work properly. Maybe you can ask to @mozway. Try with `convert_dtypes(convert_string=False)`

Comment: Sure, I'll ask them that question as soon as I get the chance! I updated my answer btw ;) And with `convert_string=False`, we get `object` dtype..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the approach as follows:

```
def check_num_or_colseq(row):
    return len(row)==6 or (row[0]=='col1' and row[1]=='col2' and row[2]=='col3' and row[3]=='col4' and row[4]=='col5' and row[5]=='col6')

 // suppose you read the csv file
    readervar = csv.reader(file)
    for i,row in enumrate(readervar):
          if check_num_or_colseq(row):
              skip = i 
              break

df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows = skip + 1)
```

I think all of the code above is self-explanatory. Hope this helps.

Comment: You read the file twice especially if the file is large but your solution works well too. +1